# Как залочить границу окна в Visual Studio '15?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Создал приложение, а именно UWP в Visual Studio 2015 на основе HTML/CSS/JS, которое добавляет 2 к числу которое вы вписали по нажатию кнопки, и захотел прикрепить к нему картинку, как фон. Фон задал в CSS.

```
background: url(/images/kartinka.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
```

Но картинка при растягивании становится некрасивой и хочется сделать так, чтобы окно **нельзя** было растягивать.

[image]

Например происходит такое - при растягивании по оси "y" картинка не тянется.

Но надо сделать так, что бы окно вообще не растягивалось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как окно выглядит при растягивании.

Спасибо тем кто помог с организацией вопроса.

Comment: Конечно, код лучше всегда прикладывать

Comment: А конкретно чего код? CSS? Просто мне кажется размер где то не там надо задавать.

Comment: А причём тут, пардон, Visual Studio?

Comment: @VladD я это все в визуал студио делаю, как UWP на JS.

Comment: @ov3rt4ke: Ах, это UWP! Самую важную деталь-то вы и пропустили.

Comment: @VladD извиняюсь) Это мой первый вопрос на таком форуме.

Comment: Да, и имеет смысл приложить минимальный код, иллюстрирующий проблему. На вопрос без кода отвечать сложнее.

Comment: @VladD а конкретно откуда, с какого файла код скинуть? я уже пробовал сделать размер в css, но размер окна всё еще можно изменять. 

`body {
    background: url(/images/prazdnik_den_zemli_kartinka.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    max-height: 412;
    max-width: 550;
}`

Comment: @VladD я пытался лазить в виндовсовском фале base.js, который декларирует почти все про UWP на JavaScript, но поискав size, width/length, form и еще несколько слов, я не нашел ничего что в принципе могло бы касаться размера окна. Смотрел в основном по названию функции или объекта в котором находилось ключевое слово.

Comment: @ov3rt4ke: Я не в курсе, js не моя тема. Подождём, пока подтянутся специалисты.

Comment: Старайтесь добавить весь код, с помощью котрого отвечающие могли бы воспроизвести Вашу проблему. Также указывайте технологии, с которыми Вы работаете. Обновите вопрос, это будет лучше всего.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Есть, исправлено.

Comment: Похоже, зафиксировать размер окна **нелзя**. Можно только поставить минимальный размер окна. Ссылка на пояснение [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e67eca4e-4552-4b35-b532-20d7877af0e4/uwpwindows-10-universal-app-disable-window-mode-resizing?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо большое, я почему то долго искал, но не нашел этого

Answer (score 1):

Так как приложения UWP универсальные, то зафиксировать ширину и высоту окна не получится.
Можно воспользоваться классом [ApplicationView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) и задать предпочитаемый размер экрана приложения с помощью PreferredLaunchViewSize

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchViewSize = preferredLaunchViewSize;
```

или задать минимальный размер с помощью

```
applicationView.setPreferredMinSize(minSize);
```

Я бы на вашем месте еще воспользовался CSS media и создал бы несколько вариантов картинки:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1279px) 
{
background: url(/images/kartinka.jpg) no-repeat;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 639px) 
{
background: url(/images/kartinkasmall.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```